# Intellij IDEA 12. Return to last active tab

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I configure Intelli-J IDEA to show last visited tab after closing current tab (as in `Eclipse`)?

Example: I opened `User.java` tab, then opened another tab and closed it. But after closing tab IDE shows me any random tab, but I want navigate back to the `User.java` tab.

Comment: @multidynamics gave the answer!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This has been fixed in recent versions of IntelliJ. However, it requires you to change a setting:

1. *Preferences*>>Editor>>*General*>>*Editor Tabs*
2. Set *When closing active editor:* to *Activate most recently opened Tab*

[image]

Comment: Works in IntelliJ 2016.1.3

Comment: How is this not the default setting? While navigating the default setting leads to confusion.

Comment: "Activate most recently opened Tab" should be the default setting! :) thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Use `CTRL + ALT + ←` to the previous tab.

OR
`CTRL + E` to see recent files opened.

Answer (score 6):

This is not yet possible, but is planned for IntelliJ 13: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106160

You can vote for this issue to make it more "important" in the backlog.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to the correct one? This has been implemented and your answer is now outdated.

Comment: this issue is fixed, follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521384/3708462 this answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

recent files opened.